# Pandas dataframe issue with date time when using functions

Tags: python, pandas, function, date

I am using two functions to filter out some values such as remove null values. The functions seems to work fine but at some point there is an issue in converting a column to a date type. It works but not entirely.

Here, i am passing first function value to second functions as the second function needs the return value to be the parameter of it

When I print the results of the function. I get the following:

```
print(is_string_date_in_right_format(remove_null(df)))

# returns a table with 
id , color , date (in string format)
1  , red   ,  '05/01/2012'
        
-- here i am converting the 3rd column to datetime
date_conv = is_string_date_in_right_format(remove_null(df))['date'] = pd.to_datetime(is_string_date_in_right_format(remove_null(df))["date"])

print(date_conv) # shows all the dates converted to DateTime (which is what I want)

results:
2021-05-01
2021-01-01
and so on.....
```

however, when I try to do the comparison by selecting data based on the timeframe it doesn't show me the data with the DateTime as it did when I run the print statement above due to which the code below is also not working. I am trying the following:

I tried to use directly the variable  date_conv in the second line of code below but it threw 'Key Error'

```
date_convert = print(is_string_date_in_right_format(remove_null(df)))      

required_id = (date_convert['date'] >= date1) & (date_convert['date'] <= date_2) 

new_d = date_convert[required_id]

print(new_d) # shows me no results it says empty data frame
```

-- date 1 and date 2 are in the format 2021-04-19 (same as the above print statement)

Comment: `date_convert = print()`. You need to remove `print()` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned, do not assign the result of `print()` to a variable.
You are expecting a DataFrame so the assign sentence should return one. Otherwise you will get a `KeyError` in the following sentences since `date_convert` does not have any value or it is not in the expected format.

By doing this:

```
date_convert = print(is_string_date_in_right_format(remove_null(df)))
```

`date_convert` will be `NoneType`.

Additionally, a function named `is_...` makes one think the function returns a boolean value instead of a DataFrame. I suggest you to change the function name to avoid confusion.